# What does a USB stick do on a powered USB port when PC is turned off?

Tags: laptop, usb, battery

There are USB ports that are powered, even if the Laptop is turned off. AFAIK, those ports have yellow color or they have a USB icon and a battery icon.

It's clear to me that I can e.g. load my phone via that port, even when the laptop is turned off. This will of course leach my laptop's battery.

However, I sometimes attach USB memory sticks to the laptop and forget to remove it. What happens in such a case? Will the USB stick be turned on, because it's powered? Will it also leach my laptop's battery? Or does it recognize that there's no data activity and turn itself off?

Is it possible to give a generic answer or does it depend on the laptop model or the USB memory stick model?

Answer (score 3):

If the USB port supplies power then yes, the USB device will consume some. It may detect that no data connection is being made and so may drain *very little* (on the order of milliwatts), but will never drain none.

Comment: Depends on what controller the USB device uses.

Comment: Ok, that's a good hint. So if I find out about the controller (e.g. in Windows device properties) I could then look up if my stick is "safe" or not

Comment: Not the host controller, the device controller. You likely have to physically disassemble the device to find out what controller it uses.

Comment: Argh. So I'll use a power meter, insert it into a USB cable, connect the stick via the cable and finally measure it. OMG, I see me doing that. It'll be a mess :-)

Comment: That's quite likely not going to help. USB ports require some form of negotiation before it draws power. Also, my laptop, if I leave my USB Mouse plugged in, which has led lights, and then turn off the pc, the mouse stays lit for a while before it turns off too. My laptop does not have a yellow border or a battery icon in the usb though.

Comment: USB ports on a *live* system can be expected to provide at least 100mA of current, with negotiation making up to at least 500mA available. On a powered-down system anything can go.

Answer (score 2):

When a PC is turned off (soft-off), most desktop systems will have all USB ports in "hot standby", keeping VBUS voltage ON. This power comes from PSU standby voltage rails, and is used to wake the computer up from mice and keyboards.

When a USB host goes off or goes asleep, the USB traffic ceases as well. USB has defined a special feature for this case called SUSPEND. When USB active traffic stops (start of frames are no longer there), every USB device is supposed to go into SUSPEND. It takes 3 ms to go into suspend state after the last active USB packet. In suspend state every USB device is supposed to enter then a  "low-power" state and consume no more than 500 uA from VBUS, or less than 2.5 mW of power [excluding USB hubs, which can have 5X more]. There is a corresponding RESUME mechanism, and REMOTE WAKE-UP mechanism within USB framework.

When a memory stick experiences the SUSPEND situation, it goes into low-power state (500uA limit). In most bus-powered situations (when power comes from VBUS) with memory modules the consumption of flash memory chips would exceed the 2.5 mW threshold, so USB-flash bridges would power the memory chip completely off, and lose all configuration data. Then the RESUME happens, system software goes all over of re-discovery of storage volumes.

And yes, because of this extra power drain most laptops have deployed "cold SUSPEND" on USB ports and turn the VBUS power completely OFF on some or all USB ports.